# Powershell script for Out of Office

Tags: powershell

I'm running the following PS1 script:

```
$userIdentity = "Firstname.Lastname"
$startTime = "06/13/18 13:00:00"
$endTime = "06/14/18 18:00:00"
$internalMessage = "Internal Message"
$externalMessage = "External Message"
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity $userIdentity -InternalMessage $internalMessage -ExternalMessage $externalMessage -AutoReplyState Scheduled -StartTime "$startTime" -EndTime "$endTime"
```

But it's failing with the following error:

```
Cmdlet error with following error message:
System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException: 
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'StartTime'
Cannot convert value "13/06/2018 13:00:00" to type "System.DateTime". 
Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

It looks like a system.datetime formatting issue, ie UK rather that US format or similar, but the following:

```
[datetime] "06/13/18 13:00:00"
```

*returns*

```
13 June 2018 13:00:00
```

So the system is obviously translating it ok - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Convert the strings to `DateTime` objects *before* passing them to `Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration`?

Comment: Your code is `06/13` but the error is `13/06` - which format are you actually using? My current script for this is using a string (not datetime object) but in the US date format rather than my native UK.

Comment: Powershell expects the date in mm/dd/yy format, but translates it based on your region to the correct format dd/mm/yy.

Comment: OK then, only difference I can see is I don't have seconds on my times, they're just hour/minute - `13:00`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately even after removing the seconds, I still have the same message.

Comment: why would you parse `-StartTime "$startTime" -EndTime "$endTime"` in string format rather than their normal DateTime? Try parsing without `"`: `-StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime`

Comment: Thanks for the response, it makes no difference though unfortunately, same message.

Comment: `[datetime]$startTime = "06/13/18 13:00:00"`. Of course you must remove the double quotes around the variables in the `Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration` statement, b/c turning a `DateTime` value back into a string before passing it to the cmdlet wouldn't make much sense, would it?

Answer (score 0):

We've experienced this problem recently as well.

What we've noticed is that if the Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration command is used in a shell where the culture is outside of "en-us" it won't parse the dates correctly.

Use this in your powershell session to check the culture;

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

If it's anything other than "en-us" try setting your OS display language to "en-us" (Make sure the region is set to "Match Windows Display language"). You should reload the shell after the Language change.

Once we were in the en-us region dates parsed fine.